# Can't run scapy after installing using Homebrew-python - OS X Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, osx-mavericks, homebrew, scapy

I tried to install scapy using Homebrew-python (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python) on my Mac running Mavericks, and it went successfully (scaly was installed).

But when I try to run scapy with:

```
from scapy.all import *
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scapy.all
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What does `which python` show you?

Comment: You are using the system python.  Did you modify the `PATH` variable to search /usr/local/bin first?  The homebrew python is in /usr/local/bin/python.

Comment: I tried doing it, but still 'which python' gives the same results. Can you help me with the process? Perhaps I'm missing something

Comment: You have to source the file afterwards.  If you modified .bashrc, you would do `source .bashrc` for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have done this already, but try running these two steps and see if that solves the problem:

```
brew doctor
brew update
```

Comment: I did and did it again now, yet with no success in running scapy